How do I use PymuPDF/fitz to denormalize xobjects?
I have a PDF that contains some xobjects. I need to denormlize them, i.e. make a copy of each xobject in every place it appears in the document. How can I do this using PymuPDF/fitz?
I've been reading the documentation and asking ChatGPT,  but this has only got me part of the way there. I can find the xobjects like so:
    for page_number in range(len(pdf_document)):
        page = pdf_document.load_page(page_number)
        xobjects = page.get_xobjects()
        for xobject in xobjects:
            ...

ChatGPT tells me to extract the stream from the individual xobjects and then insert them into a copy of the original PDF, which sounds correct, but it doesn't know the correct syntax to do this, and I haven't been able to figure it out.
Can someone give me a code snippet that denormalizes PDF xobjects?

Have a look here for an example script. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

Creator of PyMuPDF. You're a legend! :-)
